# How do I translate this Perl upload script to C#?

Tags: c#, perl, post, upload, rapidshare

I'm currently trying to port my Perl upload script to C#, but I'm not quite familiar with the language and can't get it working. I've tried it a long time but nothing seems to work. I appreciate any help. :)

Perl version:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common;
my ($user, $pass, $type, $fileName);

# This chapter sets some vars and parses some vars.
$/         = undef;
$SIG{PIPE} = 'IGNORE';
$fileName  = $ARGV[0] || die "Syntax: $0 <filename to upload> <free|prem|col> [login] [password]\n";
$type      = $ARGV[1] || "";
$user      = $ARGV[2] || "";
$pass      = $ARGV[3] || "";

# RapidShare API Documentation @ http://images.rapidshare.com/apidoc.txt

my $nextuploadserver = get('http://rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?sub=nextuploadserver');
die 'nextuploadserver broken' if $nextuploadserver !~ /^\d+$/;
print 'nextuploadserver:' . $nextuploadserver . "\n";

my $userAgent = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $request   = POST 'http://rs' . $nextuploadserver . '.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi',
  Content_Type => 'form-data',
  Content      => [
    sub         => 'upload',
    login       => $user,
    password    => $pass,
    filename    => $fileName,
    filecontent => [$fileName],
  ];
my $response = $userAgent->request($request);
die 'fucked up' if $response->is_error();
print $response->content . "\n";
```

C#, that's what I have tried:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers["Content-Type"] = "form-data";
System.Text.UTF8Encoding utf8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
string a = utf8.GetString(
wc.UploadData(
@"https://rs702l3.rapidshare.com/
cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi", "POST", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
"sub=upload&login=XXXX&password=XXXX&folder=0&filename=Test.jpg
&filecontent=" + utf8.GetString(File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\Test.jpg")))));

Console.WriteLine("Test: " + a);
```

P.S.: If anyone is looking for a Rapidshare uplaod script which is working, you are free to use mine as I posted it in the thread. :)

Comment: What isn't working?  Do you get back an exception or random characters or?

Answer (score 1):

Here's some c# POST code we're using:

```
string uri = "http://...";
string parameters = String.Format("param1={0}&param2={1}",
                                  HttpUtility.UrlEncode(param1),
                                  HttpUtility.UrlEncode(param2));

HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
webRequest.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 1;

byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(parameters);
Stream os = null;
try {
    webRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    os = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
    os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // Handle exception
} finally {
    if (os != null) {
        os.Close();
    }
}
```